Issues trying to deploy a contract using Hardhat Ignition
$ npx hardhat ignition deploy ./ignition/modules/Token.js --network sepolia
An unexpected error occurred:

AggregateError: 
    at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1118:18)
    at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1186:5)
    at Timeout.internalConnectMultipleTimeout (node:net:1712:5)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:583:11)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:519:7) {
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  [errors]: [
    Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 3.233.201.121:443
        at createConnectionError (node:net:1648:14)
        at Timeout.internalConnectMultipleTimeout (node:net:1707:38)
        at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:583:11)
        at processTimers (node:internal/timers:519:7) {
      errno: -110,
      code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
      syscall: 'connect',
      address: '3.233.201.121',
      port: 443
    },
    Error: connect ENETUNREACH 64:ff9b::1716:2e0b:443 - Local (:::0)
        at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1182:16)
        at Timeout.internalConnectMultipleTimeout (node:net:1712:5)
        at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:583:11)
        at processTimers (node:internal/timers:519:7) {
      errno: -101,
      code: 'ENETUNREACH',
      syscall: 'connect',
      address: '64:ff9b::1716:2e0b',
      port: 443
    },
    Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 34.232.87.70:443
        at createConnectionError (node:net:1648:14)
        at Timeout.internalConnectMultipleTimeout (node:net:1707:38)
        at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:583:11)
        at processTimers (node:internal/timers:519:7) {
      errno: -110,
      code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
      syscall: 'connect',
      address: '34.232.87.70',
      port: 443
    },
    Error: connect ENETUNREACH 64:ff9b::3e4:9518:443 - Local (:::0)
        at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1182:16)
        at Timeout.internalConnectMultipleTimeout (node:net:1712:5)
        at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:583:11)
        at processTimers (node:internal/timers:519:7) {
      errno: -101,
      code: 'ENETUNREACH',
      syscall: 'connect',
      address: '64:ff9b::3e4:9518',
      port: 443
    },
    Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 54.152.69.97:443
        at createConnectionError (node:net:1648:14)
        at Timeout.internalConnectMultipleTimeout (node:net:1707:38)
        at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:583:11)
        at processTimers (node:internal/timers:519:7) {
      errno: -110,
      code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
      syscall: 'connect',
      address: '54.152.69.97',
      port: 443
    },
    Error: connect ENETUNREACH 64:ff9b::2cce:2ab9:443 - Local (:::0)
        at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1182:16)
        at Timeout.internalConnectMultipleTimeout (node:net:1712:5)
        at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:583:11)
        at processTimers (node:internal/timers:519:7) {
      errno: -101,
      code: 'ENETUNREACH',
      syscall: 'connect',
      address: '64:ff9b::2cce:2ab9',
      port: 443
    },
    Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 3.209.237.124:443
        at createConnectionError (node:net:1648:14)
        at Timeout.internalConnectMultipleTimeout (node:net:1707:38)
        at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:583:11)
        at processTimers (node:internal/timers:519:7) {
      errno: -110,
      code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
      syscall: 'connect',
      address: '3.209.237.124',
      port: 443
    },
    Error: connect ENETUNREACH 64:ff9b::22e8:5746:443 - Local (:::0)
        at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1182:16)
        at Timeout.internalConnectMultipleTimeout (node:net:1712:5)
        at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:583:11)
        at processTimers (node:internal/timers:519:7) {
      errno: -101,
      code: 'ENETUNREACH',
      syscall: 'connect',
      address: '64:ff9b::22e8:5746',
      port: 443
    },
    Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 3.228.149.24:443
        at createConnectionError (node:net:1648:14)
        at Timeout.internalConnectMultipleTimeout (node:net:1707:38)
        at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:583:11)
        at processTimers (node:internal/timers:519:7) {
      errno: -110,
      code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
      syscall: 'connect',
      address: '3.228.149.24',
      port: 443
    },
    Error: connect ENETUNREACH 64:ff9b::2ccd:9d70:443 - Local (:::0)
        at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1182:16)
        at Timeout.internalConnectMultipleTimeout (node:net:1712:5)
        at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:583:11)
        at processTimers (node:internal/timers:519:7) {
      errno: -101,
      code: 'ENETUNREACH',
      syscall: 'connect',
      address: '64:ff9b::2ccd:9d70',
      port: 443
    },
    Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 44.205.157.112:443
        at createConnectionError (node:net:1648:14)
        at Timeout.internalConnectMultipleTimeout (node:net:1707:38)
        at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:583:11)
        at processTimers (node:internal/timers:519:7) {
      errno: -110,
      code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
      syscall: 'connect',
      address: '44.205.157.112',
      port: 443
    },
    Error: connect ENETUNREACH 64:ff9b::3d1:ed7c:443 - Local (:::0)
        at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1182:16)
        at Timeout.internalConnectMultipleTimeout (node:net:1712:5)
        at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:583:11)
        at processTimers (node:internal/timers:519:7) {
      errno: -101,
      code: 'ENETUNREACH',
      syscall: 'connect',
      address: '64:ff9b::3d1:ed7c',
      port: 443
    },
    Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 52.7.14.128:443
        at createConnectionError (node:net:1648:14)
        at Timeout.internalConnectMultipleTimeout (node:net:1707:38)
        at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:583:11)
        at processTimers (node:internal/timers:519:7) {
      errno: -110,
      code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
      syscall: 'connect',
      address: '52.7.14.128',
      port: 443
    },
    Error: connect ENETUNREACH 64:ff9b::3698:4561:443 - Local (:::0)
        at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1182:16)
        at Timeout.internalConnectMultipleTimeout (node:net:1712:5)
        at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:583:11)
        at processTimers (node:internal/timers:519:7) {
      errno: -101,
      code: 'ENETUNREACH',
      syscall: 'connect',
      address: '64:ff9b::3698:4561',
      port: 443
    },
    Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 44.206.42.185:443
        at createConnectionError (node:net:1648:14)
        at Timeout.internalConnectMultipleTimeout (node:net:1707:38)
        at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:583:11)
        at processTimers (node:internal/timers:519:7) {
      errno: -110,
      code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
      syscall: 'connect',
      address: '44.206.42.185',
      port: 443
    },
    Error: connect ENETUNREACH 64:ff9b::12eb:9d8e:443 - Local (:::0)
        at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1182:16)
        at Timeout.internalConnectMultipleTimeout (node:net:1712:5)
        at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:583:11)
        at processTimers (node:internal/timers:519:7) {
      errno: -101,
      code: 'ENETUNREACH',
      syscall: 'connect',
      address: '64:ff9b::12eb:9d8e',
      port: 443
    }
  ]
}

Can someone please help me out with this error, I tried to look into it, as far as I understand it's something related to network issues? I checked my RPC endpoint is active and running properly.

The error seems to be a problem with the connection. Ensure the RPC node is reachable.

@Ismael Hello, I did check my RPC node is active and reachable. I tried to run the same node for deployment using forge and it worked, so I'm clueless what the actual issue might be, I also tried unchecking IPv6 in my network properties just to check if it was IP related issue, but that didn't work as well.

Update: I tried deleting and making a new Infura API Key but it still doesn't work for some reason, tried Alchemy had same errors, kept trying using new API keys and now Alchemy seems to work. Honestly don't know what the issue exactly is cos the RPC nodes were all active and working
